# Flickering of Image drawn in panel during re-sizing and scrolling (C#) -VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have been trying to make an image drawn in a panel to not flicker during re-sizing and scrolling of the form containing the panel. Here is the code. But it doesn't work, what is wrong with it? Please help me.

```
   private void viewMode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (sender is ToolStripMenuItem)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem tlStrpMI = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
            _selectedMode = (DisplayMode)ctxtMenuVw.Items.IndexOf(tlStrpMI) 

            switch (_selectedMode)
            {
                case DisplayMode.ScaleToFit:
                    panelPhoto.AutoScroll = false;
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
                    panelPhoto.Invalidate();
                    break;
                case DisplayMode.StretchToFit:
                    panelPhoto.AutoScroll = false;
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
                    panelPhoto.Invalidate();
                    break;
                case DisplayMode.ActualSize:
                    panelPhoto.AutoScroll = true;
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, false);
                    panelPhoto.Invalidate();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Try setting DoubleBuffered control property to true

Comment: Use a __doublebuffered__ `Panel` __subclass__: `public class DrawPanel : Panel { public DrawPanel() { this.DoubleBuffered = true;}}` Add this to your project, compile and use instead of a simple Panel. Or use a `PictureBox`, which is DoubleBuffered by default.